# how to set a Property name based on another Property in Application.yaml

Tags: spring-boot, properties, configuration, cloud-foundry

I have a dynamic service name and to configure it in the application.yml I'm trying to set it up using

```
my_service: ${vcap.services.${service_name}.credentials.hostname}
```

It fails parsing the document, trying using 2 different properties

```
my_property: vcap.services.${service_name}.credentials.hostname
my_service: ${my_property}
```

In this case it can compose the property name correctly but it uses that content as a string, not resolving it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a property reference another property (i.e. nested), but you can't embed a property inside another property.

This works (Spring Boot 2.1 & Spring 5.1):

```
my.url=http://localhost:8888/service/${nestedProperty}
nestedProperty=foo/bar/baz
```

but as you've found this does not properly parse:

```
my_service: ${vcap.services.${service_name}.credentials.hostname}
```

I was able to get something working using a combination of property place holder and SPEL.

```
vcap:
  services:
    test-db:
      credentials:
        hostname: freedom
service_name: test-db
my_service: "#{'${vcap.services.${service_name}.credentials.hostname}'}"
```

Obviously you can leave out the `vcap` part, I just did that to make testing easier. Using `'${..}'` will cause SPEL to look up a property & it seems like that is capable of parsing an embedded property.

It's all kinda ugly though. You might want to consider using profiles to conditionally wire up different database dependencies, or use [java-cfenv](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv) to obtain Cloud Foundry provided service info.

Hope that helps!